# IntentService not call api when App closed

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-service-binding

I have created one `IntentService` to send local data to the server.

I am calling this `service` from two different `broadcast receivers`.
1) When from  Connectivity change receiver.
2) on 12 am with alarm manager

Its working fine when an app is open.
But not working when an app is closed.

Below is my **`IntentService`** code.

```
public class ExpertEventService extends IntentService {
@Inject
Context context;
@Inject
Realm realm;

public ExpertEventService() {
    super("ExpertEventService");
    Log.e("expertEvent", "service constructor");
    // Toothpick.inject(this, Toothpick.openScope(Constants.APPSCOPENAME));
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    Toothpick.inject(this, Toothpick.openScope(Constants.APPSCOPENAME));
    Log.e("expertEvent", "service started");
    RealmResults<AskExpertEventModel> results = realm.where(AskExpertEventModel.class).findAll();
    List<AskExpertEventModel> requestList = realm.copyFromRealm(results);
    String language = realm.where(LanguageStore.class).equalTo(LanguageStore.ISSELECTED, true).findAll().first().getCode();
    String appInstanceCode = Preferences.getAppInstanceCode(context);
    String token = Preferences.getToken(context);
    Api.userManagement(context).expertEvent(appInstanceCode, token, language, requestList)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new ApiSuccess<EventResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void call(EventResponse eventResponse) {
                    Log.e("expertEvent", eventResponse.getStatus());
                    if (eventResponse.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.Status.STATUS_SUCCESS)) {
                        Log.e("expertEvent", "sucess");

                       new RealmDB().deleteEvent();;
                    }

                }
            }, new ApiFail() {
                @Override
                public void httpStatus(HttpErrorResponse response) {
                    Log.e("expertEvent", response.getError());
                }

                @Override
                public void noNetworkError() {
                    Log.e("expertEvent", "no network connection");
                }

                @Override
                public void unknownError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.e("expertEvent", e.getMessage());
                }
            });

  }

}
```

1) Receiver called when connectivity change

```
     public class NetworkStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e("expertEvent", "Connectivity changed");
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) 
   context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (info != null) {
        if (info.isConnected()) {
            //start service

            Log.e("expertEvent", "Connected ");
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, 
             ExpertEventService.class);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);


        }
    } else {
        Log.e("expertEvent", "not connected");
    }
}
  }
```

2)  Execute when 12 am

```
        public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //call service
    Log.e("alarmreceiver","in  alarm receiver");
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, ExpertEventService.class);
    context.startService(serviceIntent);

}
   }
```

Comment: Please share start ExpertEventService code (BroadcastReceivers)

Comment: `IntentService` stops when it's done with executing `intent`. You either need `Service` that can constantly run in background, or use `BroadcastReceiver` to start `IntentService` when needed.

Comment: Added service called code from broadcast receiver @JRamesh

Comment: yes I am calling intent service from the broadcast receiver whenever needed @Michal_196

Comment: are you testing on Android O?

Comment: No. testing on Nogut @Benjamin

Comment: Are you able to print that log in `AlarmReceiver` when app is closed?

Comment: no not printing logs. But I am cross check with databse. After calling API I am deleting my records from local database @Michal_196